# Buildpacks Distroless runtime image support

Tags: buildpack, paketo

Is it possible to use [distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) image with buildpacks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessarily an easy question and it depends.

You are able to create a [custom stack](https://buildpacks.io/docs/operator-guide/create-a-stack/) and [custom builder](https://buildpacks.io/docs/operator-guide/create-a-builder/), which you can base off distroless.

If you're unsure about these buildpack terms, the stack provides the base images for building and running applications. The builder is the combination of the stack plus a set of buildpacks that can run on that stack.

So in theory, the answer to your question is yes. Where it becomes difficult to answer is that you haven't indicated anything about your application (language/runtime?) or the buildpacks (heroku, paketo, etc?) you need to run. Your application, language runtime, and buildpacks will need to be able to run on distroless, which isn't trivial because it is an extremely spartan container image.

In short, you'll need to update the question to provide more details about your app and the buildpacks you want to run to get a more definitive answer.

---

Taking a guess here, if you are running Paketo buildpacks, what I can say is that Paketo provides a "tiny" image (less than 20M) that is similar to distroless. You could a.) **look at using the tiny stack as all the hard work is done for you** or b.) if you really need distroless, you could try to base your work off the tiny stack. Because that's also a stripped-down image, the buildpacks and apps you can run on tiny are likely similar to what you could run on distroless.

You can find the [tiny builder definition here](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/tiny-builder/) and you can find [tiny stack releases here](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/tiny-stack-release) and [tiny stack source here](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/stacks/tree/main/tiny).

Comment: thanks for quick response. Sorry i forgot to provide more details. You are right, i am using paketo tiny stack. But i am running into issue. This is a simple Spring boot app. As per doc it says it supports Java but i dont think it doesn't as the builder doesn't have java buildpack. 

```
ERROR: No buildpack groups passed detection.
ERROR: Please check that you are running against the correct path.
ERROR: failed to detect: no buildpacks participating
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 20
```

Comment: So i switched to using procfile, it successfully build the image but ran into issue when i ran the docker as it doesn't have java
```
ERROR: failed to launch: path lookup: exec: "java": executable file not found in $PATH
```
Here is the sample repo for testing: https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started

Comment: It should work on the base stack. The `Procfile` in that example is not needed and breaking things, it has an incorrect start command if you're using Paketo buildpacks. Just remove the file & `pack build` it should work. The tiny stack should work but doesn't, that is an oversight on my part. The builder should have included the Java buildpack and it doesn't, sorry. I'll get a PR in for that. In the meantime, run `pb java-getting-started -B paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny -b paketo-buildpacks/java`. Same thing goes for the Procfile, delete it. That'll work.

Comment: Thanks @daniel-mikusa, i was able to get Java app working by adding Java Buildpack to tiny builder. Are they any plans to support nodejs app with tiny stack like https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/tree/main/nodejs. I am open for contribution back to paketo, i just need some documentation on how to debug buildpack with builder if you have does details can you share it with me

Comment: I don't know about Node.js. I don't work on those buildpacks. As far as how-to debug, I would suggest you join our Slack, it would be easier to discuss stuff like that there, or open new questions. https://paketobuildpacks.slack.com.